# How to proxy/forward backend API request for PRODUCTION?

Tags: angular

Angular v12 needs to send request to an existing API backend, say `localhost:4200/post1` to be `https://backend/api/post1`. **proxy.conf.js** makes that happen for `localhost` DEV server when `ng serve`.

Build and deployed to PROD server, request to API always get **404**. `POST https://prod/post1 404`. Based on [Angular Proxying to a backend server](https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server), proxy.conf.js is for DEV server running `ng serve` only, this is confirmed by many others. But in the same doc [Rewrite the URL path](https://angular.io/guide/build#rewrite-the-url-path), it also introduces `pathRewrite` to rewrite the URL path **at run time**, an example given is to remove "api".

Confusing but assume pathRewrite does help for PROD run time, instead of removing "api", I want to give a new full URL: `/post1` to `https://backend/api/post1`?

This is my current proxy.conf.js getting 404 at PROD server:

```
const PROXY_CONFIG = 
[
    {
        context: 
        [
            "/post1"
        ],

        "target" : "https://backend/api",     // so "localhost:4200/post1" forward to "https://backend/api"
        "changeOrigin": true,       
        "pathRewrite": { ??? : ??? }    // how to implement in place of ???
    }
]
module.exports = PROXY_CONFIG;
```

Comment: That whole section is for Webpack dev server's proxy, which you're **not** going to be running in production. It's not to rewrite the code in your actual app. For that you either want the environments feature at build time, or some runtime configuration (I've written about this here: https://blog.jonrshar.pe/2020/Sep/19/spa-config.html).

Comment: Proxy config isn’t Gona help you in prod. It sounds like you don’t need one at all. Just use environments and file replacement to set your api base url.

Comment: @bryan60 Thanks for the confirmation. Is there any sample, or document, or anything I can read about? Thanks again.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/build

Comment: @jonrsharpe Glad to see **This is quite a common problem**, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

## Production

You should be setting a reverse proxy in your HTTP server (Apache/Nginx).

Here's an example with Nginx (location answer your question), create a file `/etc/nginx/conf.d/example.com.conf`:

```json
server {
    listen         80;
    listen         [::]:80;
    server_name    example.com www.example.com;
    root           /var/www/example.com;
    index          index.html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;

    location /api/ {
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
    }
}
```

Here you can find additional information: [Angular Doc](https://angular.io/guide/deployment)

## Development

For development, you should create a proxy.conf.json file:

```json
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://localhost:3000",
    "secure": false
  }
}
```

Then you should change `npm start` command in your package.json:

```json
"start": "ng serve  --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
```

Here you can find additional information: [Angular Doc](https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server)